# Application-defined or object-defined error for if block

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have written the below piece of code in VBA that basically checks if the value  in cell B24 is positive and if positive it iterates through a for-loop for 50 times where X0 and sqrt are repeatedly updated.

However when I debug the code it throws an error

```
'Run-time error '1004'
  Application-defined or object-defined error.
```

I checked the syntax, it looks fine but the error keeps popping. How to resolve this issue? Help pls

```
Sub forloopCalc()

Dim X0, sqrt As Integer
Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = "Sheet1"
    Dim WSD As Worksheet
    Set WSD = Worksheets(sheetName)
    

If (Cells(B, 24).Value > 0) Then
    X0 = 5.96046447753906E-08
    sqrt = 0.000244140625
    For i = 0 To 50
        If ((X0 - Cells(B, 24).Value) < 0) Then
            X0 = X0 * 4
            sqrt = sqrt * 2
        Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End If

WSD.Cells(P, 24).Value = X0
WSD.Cells(R, 24).Value = sqrt
     

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim X0, sqrt As Integer` makes X0 a variant by default and sqrt an Integer by design. At `X0 = 5.96046447753906E-08` I would prefer X0 to be a Double and `sqrt = 0.000244140625` assigns 0 to the integer sqrt. sqrt should be of Double data type as well if you want to assign a fraction to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line (and the others):

```
If (Cells(B, 24).Value > 0) Then
```

`B` is seen as a variable with initial value `0`, and not as a literal row reference. Also `"B"` can only be used for columns and not rows. Also cell `B24` is **column B, row 24**, and the parameters in `Cells` are `rowIndex, colIndex`.

Write:

```
If (Cells(24, "B").Value > 0) Then
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I really didnt realise that it was taking B as variable and also mixed up the order. Thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

The version of your code below actually runs. Please use its syntax as a base for your further efforts.

```
Sub forloopCalc()

    Dim X0          As Double
    Dim sqrt        As Double
    Dim WsD         As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName   As String
    Dim i           As Integer
    
    sheetName = "Sheet1"
    Set WsD = Worksheets(sheetName)
        
    If (WsD.Cells(24, "B").Value > 0) Then
        X0 = 5.96046447753906E-08
        sqrt = 0.000244140625
        For i = 0 To 50
            If (X0 - WsD.Cells(24, "B").Value < 0) Then
                X0 = X0 * 4
                sqrt = sqrt * 2
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    WsD.Cells(24, "P").Value = X0
    WsD.Cells(24, "R").Value = sqrt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to use Range. e.g. Range("B24")

```
Sub forloopCalc()

Dim X0, sqrt As Integer
Dim sheetName As String
Dim WSD As Worksheet

sheetName = "Sheet1"
Set WSD = Worksheets(sheetName)
      

If (Range("B24").Value > 0) Then
    X0 = 5.96046447753906E-08
    sqrt = 0.000244140625
    For i = 0 To 50
        If ((X0 - Range("B24").Value) < 0) Then
            X0 = X0 * 4
            sqrt = sqrt * 2
        Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End If

WSD.Range("P24").Value = X0
WSD.Range("R24").Value = sqrt

End Sub
```